# How to stop enqueued call after first execution?

Tags: android, okhttp, enqueue

I'm very new to android development. Trying to connect some site and get data from it. I have this function called only from onCreate in the main activity. Every time I turn virtual Android phone left or right I see new "run()" strings in EditText and requests in Wireshark. How to stop that properly?

Tried call.cancel() and mClient.dispatcher().cancelAll() inside OnResponse

```
protected void Load(String url) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    mClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEdit.setText(mEdit.getText() + "run()\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: This happens because of reconfiguration. You activity gets recreated every time you turn your phone, hence your onCreate is called again and again which inturn will invoke you loadString method.

Comment: I've added traces at beginnings of onCreate and Load. After some turns "onCreate" and "Load" are printed only once and "run" are many https://imgur.com/dN0Inkr

Answer (score 0):

retrofit supports enqueue canceling, and it works great. 
And i think if you will try to run this code - your client enqueues would be stoped

```
protected void Load(String url) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Call<Response> mCall = mClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                if (call.isCanceled()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "request was cancelled");
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEdit.setText(mEdit.getText() + "run()\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });

    mCall.cancel();
}
```

I don't know you project structure and what kind of patterns you using(MVP, MVVM or else), but in simple, this code can be improved by returning Call

```
protected void Load(String url): Call<Response>
```

And then you can hadle you request status, and if it longer than 5 seconds for example, you call `call.cancel()` and request is stopping.

Comment: Thanks. But in your example call cancels before execution

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is called every time configuration changes (for example you rotate your phone/emulator). For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

You can save your response to prevent new request on every onCreate. Something like this:

```
MainActivity {
  private Response savedResponse;

  onCreate() {
    if (savedResponse == null) {
      Load(url)
    }
  }
}
```

and in your onResponse save the response:

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            savedResponse = response;    // <----
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mEdit.setText(mEdit.getText() + "run()\n");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

However, correct way would be to separete network calls/requests from activity lifecycle and load data somewhere else (Service, WorkManager, ...)

Comment: I've thought about bool variable to stop Load call but this not helpes too. I've added mEdit.setText(mEdit.getText() + "Load()\n"); to the first line of Load function and it printed only once (and "onCreate" as well)

Comment: OK, to keep your variables after onDestroy, you have to implement onSaveInstanceState. Check out this section: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple,-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate

Comment: But I might be consfused, I thought you want to call your Load function only once. So it should be correct to see only one log message from first line of Load function.

Comment: Yes. I need only one Load() call and only one run(). Now I get something strange for me https://imgur.com/dN0Inkr - after four turns

Comment: Well, it is strange. I suppose you don't have "run()" log anywhere else in your code. I don't see any reason to have multiple run logs from your posted code, if you have only one Load log.